# Cant define functions properly

Tags: python, python-3.x

The assignment goes as follows:
Create a program that will ask a user the year the were born and their name. The program should:

call a function that will ask the user for input
send that information back to the main function
call a function that calculates their age
call the function to print out their age, first initial, and last name.

I tried this

````
```
def main():
    first = input('Enter your first name: ')
    last = input('Enter your last name: ')
    year = int(input('What year were you born: '))
    again = 'y'
    
    def userInput(first, last, year):
        fname = first
        lname = last
        dob = year
        return fname, lname, dob
    def calcy(dob):  
    # age calculator
        age = 2023 - dob
        return age
    
    def printy(first, last, age):
    # Print Statement
        print(f'{fname[0]} {lname} is {age} years old.')
        #play again
        again = input('Play again? (y/n)')
        while again == 'y':
            first = input('Enter your first name: ')
            last = input('Enter your last name: ')
            year = int(input('Enter your year of birth: '))
            age = 2023 - year
            print(f'{first[0]} {last} is {age} years old.')
            playagain = input('Play again? (y/n)')
        print('Thank you for playing.')
main()
```
````

I cant seem to continue the loop, and it stops after the first inputs. What am I doing wrong? It needs 4 functions (main included)

Comment: Where do you assign `again` to another value?

Comment: You are defining three functions *inside* `main` which you never actually call.

Comment: Really, a couple of errors here. You need to call your functions somewhere. As of now, your loop is never called. Plus, `playagain` is not the same variable as `again`.

Comment: I fixed my little playagain error, what am i doing wrong with the functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is almost correct! You *defined function objects* with `def` statements, but you did *call* only your `main` function object. So other function objects don't do anything yet. You called `main` function with `main()` expression statement on the last line of your program, and to get it work we want to place *other function calls* straight into the *body* of our `main` function *definition*. So we have *function definitions* at our top-level of program, but we actually call defined objects within the `main` function definition. And we do that because the program becomes more structured and although it is easy to run the program with just one `main` call, we have five different self-contained and self-sufficient function objects - so it is easy to maintain the program and expand it further.

```
def userInput():
    first = input('Enter your first name: ')
    last = input('Enter your last name: ')
    dob = int(input('Enter year you were born: '))
    return first, last, dob

def calcy(dob):
    return 2023 - dob

def printy(first_name, last_name, persons_age):
    print(f'{first_name} {last_name} is {persons_age} years old.')

def main():
    
    first, last, dob = userInput()
    age = calcy(dob)
    printy(first, last, age)
    again = input('Play again? (y/n): ')
    while again != 'n':
        first, last, dob = userInput()
        age = calcy(dob)
        printy(first, last, age)
        again = input('Play again? (y/n): ')
        
main()
```